# Memory leak when utilizing the reference counting feature of Delphi

Tags: delphi

The following code try to utilize the reference counting feature of Delphi.

However, FastMM4 in FullDebugMode reports `DoStuff1` gives memory leak while `DoStuff2` does not. Could you help to comment about why ? Shouldn't these two procedures behave exactly the same behind the scene ?

```
program Project_SO;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  FastMM4, 
  SysUtils;

type  
  ITestFunc = interface
  ['{B3F6D9A7-FC77-40CE-9BBF-C42D7037A596}']
    function DoIt(X,Y: Integer): Integer;
  end;

  TTestFunc = class(TInterfacedObject, ITestFunc)
  public
    function DoIt(X,Y: Integer): Integer;
  end;
  TTestFuncClass = class of TTestFunc;   

{ TTestFunc }

function TTestFunc.DoIt(X, Y: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := X + Y; 
end;

function DoStuff1(Num1, Num2: Integer; OperationClass: TTestFuncClass): Integer;
begin
  Result := ITestFunc(OperationClass.Create).DoIt(Num1, Num2);
end;

function DoStuff2(Num1, Num2: Integer; OperationClass: TTestFuncClass): Integer;
var I: ITestFunc;
begin
  I := ITestFunc(OperationClass.Create);
  Result := I.DoIt(Num1, Num2);
end;

begin
  Writeln(IntToStr(DoStuff1(3, 6, TTestFunc)));
  Writeln(IntToStr(DoStuff2(3, 6, TTestFunc)));
end.
```

Comment: Don't use a cast like that. Use `I := OperationClass.Create as ITestFunc;`. You could actually just do `I := OperationClass.Create;`, but that does not set the reference count to 1, which can cause problems.

Comment: @Rudy It sets the ref count to 1 when I is assigned to.

Comment: @Xichen Your class will need a virtual constructor

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - heh, not sure if you are agreeing with Rudy's comment or not but in my experience, he is right. The hard cast to ITestFunc can create problems in reference counting.

Comment: @Lieven I'm not talking about the hard cast, which is wrong. I'm talking about the second part of his comment.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  @DavidHeffernan @LievenKeersmaekers Thank you for your comments very much ! Switching to `as-cast` eliminates the memory leak !

Comment: @David: not it if is passed to a const parameter directly: `MyFunc(OperationClass.Create, ...`. That is why I prefer to always do the cast.

Comment: @Rudy Are we talking about the code in the question, and the code you repeated in the comment? Or are we talking about some other code? You said that `I := OperationClass.Create` does not take a reference. That statement is categorically wrong.

Comment: @Rudy Personally I make a local variable to defeat the defective design of passing result of constructor to const param. Each to their own.

Comment: @I was talking about code in general. I always prefer the `x as IY` variety. It shows clearer what is going on, too.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It's just that what you actually wrote is incorrect and that is confusing. At least we've cleared up the facts now.

Comment: Ok, that was wrong and confusing. It was pretty early in the morning. <g>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Result := ITestFunc(OperationClass.Create).DoIt(Num1, Num2);
```

Nowhere here is a reference to the interface taken. A reference is taken when the interface is assigned to a variable, or passed as a by value parameter. In fact, passing as a by value parameter, can be thought of as semantically equivalent to assigning to a local variable in the callee's frame.

But nowhere in this code is a reference taken. And so, since nothing has a reference to the interface, there is no mechanism for it to be destroyed. Hence the leak.

```
var 
  I: ITestFunc;
begin
  I := ITestFunc(OperationClass.Create);
  Result := I.DoIt(Num1, Num2);
end;
```

In this variant, a reference is taken when the assignment is made. When the local variable `I` leaves scope, its reference count decreases to zero and the implementing object is destroyed.

Note that the unchecked cast is needless here. The compiler knows perfectly well that `TTestFunc` implements `ITestFunc` and your code should better be written like this:

```
var 
  I: ITestFunc;
begin
  I := OperationClass.Create;
  Result := I.DoIt(Num1, Num2);
end;
```

As suggested in the comments, you could remove the local variable and use a checked `as` cast:

```
Result := (OperationClass.Create as ITestFunc).DoIt(Num1, Num2);
```

A consequence of the implementation of the `as` cast is that an implicit local variable is declared, to which the interface is assigned. That means that the reference count is incremented to one, and then decremented to zero when that implicit local leaves scope.

Finally, your `TTestFunc` class should have a virtual constructor since you intend to instantiate it with a meta class.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! Your answer says `as-cast` utilizes an implicit local variable, but `hard-cast` does not. Could you help to confirm ? (And where should people find out this info ?)

Comment: What do you mean by confirm.  The unchecked cast does not produce an implicit local, the checked cast does.  I don't believe any of this is documented anywhere. Consider this answer the next best thing.